# Microsoft Graph delta queries do not return extensionAttribute11

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to sync data from Microsoft Graph using delta queries. I need `extensionAttribute11` in `onPremisesExtensionAttributes` to be included but I do not receive it even when including it in the `$select` clause of the delta query. Is there a way to receive that data?

```
/beta/users/delta?$select=id,userType,displayName,givenName,surname,userPrincipalName,mailNickname,onPremisesExtensionAttributes,jobTitle,onPremisesImmutableId,officeLocation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't supported. From the [Known Issues documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#delta-query):

> **Delta query**
>
> - OData context is sometimes returned incorrectly when tracking changes to relationships.
> - Schema extensions (legacy) are not returned with $select statement, but are > - returned without `$select`.
> - Clients cannot track changes to open extensions or registered schema extensions.

Comment: This property is not schema extensions.  It is a sync from on-premises AD user extension attributes 1->15.  Will need to ask why this is not supported in delta query.  There may be a simple fix here...